# Where is the Ubuntu 14.04 kernel source code located?

Tags: 14.04, kernel

I want to modify and want to make my own operating system using source code, so obviously firstly I need the kernel. I've decided that I'd use the Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) kernel. Where do I download that?

Comment: Good luck! http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Linux-Linus-Torvalds-kernel-too-complex-code,14495.html :-) (really, you're probably better if you start with one of the ancient versions in a virtual machine --- and grow from there).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 has 3.13 Linux kernel installed. You can get its source code here

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/linux-source-3.13.0